# C++ STL: Using derived virtual class as "Strict Weak Ordering" for std::sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I hit a wall using std::sort(). I have a pure virtual class (named `Compare`) that the caller of a method derives from (named `MyComp`). I use the pure virtual class for my API's prototype:

```
void Object::DoSort(Compare &comp) {
    std::sort(this->mKeys.begin(),this->mKeys.end(), comp);
}
```

the caller:

```
class MyComp: public Compare {
    bool operator()(const Row *r1, const Row *r2)  { ... }
} cmp;
...
obj->DoSort(cmp);
```

The g++ compiler on Linux complains that: "cannot allocate an object of type 'Compare' since type 'Compare' has abstract virtual functions"

Even if I modify `Compare` to be simply virtual (not pure), the `std::sort()` still calls the `Compare::operator()` code instead of the `MyComp::operator()`.

Calling cmp(r1,r2) compiles fine and return the right result.

I must do something wrong, or I do not get it. Help please!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::sort` (and other STL functions) take comparator objects *by value*, so your object is being copied, but the derived part (including its vtbl) is being "sliced away".

You could wrap your object in a proxy:

```
class Proxy
{
private:
    Compare &cmp;
public:
    Proxy(Compare &cmp) : cmp(cmp) {}
    bool operator()(const Row *r1, const Row *r2) { return cmp(r1, r2); }
};


...

MyCompare cmp = MyCompare();

std::sort(x.begin(), x.end(), Proxy(cmp));
```

Comment: 1) Works like a charm. 2) STL == Evil.

Comment: @0x6adb: Evilness depends!  If you had it take by reference, you couldn't do e.g. `std::sort(x.begin, x.end(), MyComparator())`, for instance (you can't bind a non-const ref to a temporary object).

Comment: Why couldn't they overload std::sort with a version that takes the comparator as a reference? (I had to write my own).

Comment: @Super: For a start, that would cause ambiguities; the compiler wouldn't know which to call in many circumstances.